# Unexpected behavior when calling 'findnsols' in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I’m new to prolog and found this unexpected behavior when using `findnsols` (which calls `findall`). Basically, not all solutions returned satisfy the goal, which really confuses me. Do I misunderstand something?

This is the program:

```
predneg_on_obj(block1,block1).
predneg_on_obj(block2,block1).
predneg_on_obj(block2,block2).
istypeobj(block1).
istypeobj(block2).
goal(V_1) :-
    forall(member(O, [block1,block2]), predneg_on_obj(O,V_1)), 
    istypeobj(V_1).
```

And the query is:

```
findnsols(99999, V, goal(V), L)
```

By reading the program, it's obvious that `block1` satisfies the goal while `block2` doesn't. We can very this by calling `goal(block2)`, which returns false.

However the `findnsols` query returns:

```
L=[block1, block2]
```

which contains `block2`.

It's super weird to me, and I appreciate any suggestion and help from you!

Comment: Your `forall` looks strange. Compare e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2 vs https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foreach/2

Answer (score 0):

Since [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2) is a form of *failure-driven* loop, it cannot create variable bindings. So, to solve the problem, you should instantiate variable `V_1` before calling `forall/2`:

```
goal(V_1) :-
    istypeobj(V_1),  % <== instantiate variable V_1
    forall(member(O, [block1,block2]), predneg_on_obj(O,V_1)).
```

Examples:

```
?- findnsols(99999, V, goal(V), L).
L = [block1].

?- goal(block1).
true.

?- goal(block2).
false.

?- goal(V).
V = block1 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Another workaround I found is to use `foreach` instead of `forall`. I wonder do you have any thoughts on comparing these two solutions?